# Weird end values when reading from file using fgetc()

Tags: c, fgetc

I'm using `fgetc()` to read a char from a file which consists of digits only. Then I convert the characters to int and print it out. That's fine. But after printing out all the digits, at the end I get `-38-49` values. I googled it, but nothing about it there. 
In the input file, I have the following: `0105243100000002200000010001318123`
The outpuf is like this: `0105243100000002200000010001318123-38-49`
My code:

```
do
    {
        c1 = fgetc(fread)-'0';
        if (!isspace(c1))
        {
            printf("%d", c1); 
        }       
        if (feof(fread))
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (1);
```

Comment: Another issue `isspace(c1)` -> `isspace(c1+'0')`

Comment: You should either be checking `feof` before printing c1, or checking to see if `fgetc` returns `EOF` before subtracting '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the newline (10) and the EOF return value of fgetc (-1). Substracting '0' (48) from those yields those negative numbers.

Check if the char if valid, it must be in range ['0','9']

```
c1 = fgetc(fread);
if(c1 >= '0' && c1 <= '9') {
  c1 -= '0';
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When reading a file with [`fgetc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) you should check for `EOF` *first*, to detect the end of the file

```
int c, n;
while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    if (isdigit(c)) {
        n = c - '0';
        printf("%d", n);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you use the `EOF` value and get the negative result.